# soft delete column update with respect to id ,

Tags: php, cakephp

Anyone help me i am trying to delete the records in Certificates and after deleting with respect to id in Books table is_delete column should update to 0 For me it's updating but particular id is not updating all the id's are updating

public function deleteTC($id)
{

```
    $condition['Items.is_delete'] = 0;
    
    $fields = ['Books.is_delete', 'DegreeStudents.id','Items.some_id'];
    $tableList = $this->Books->find('all', ['conditions' => $condition,'fields'=>$fields, 'join' => 
        [
        'Items' => 
            [
                'table' => 'items', 'type' => 'INNER', 
                'conditions' => ['Items.some_id = Books.id','Books.is_delete'=>2],
            ]
            
          
             
          ]])->enableHydration(false)->toArray();
        foreach ($tableList as $i=>$list){
    $result = $this->Certificates->deleteData($id);

 
   
    if($result) {
       
     $condition['Certificates.is_delete'] = 1;
    {
        $this->Books->update(['id' => $list['id']], ['is_delete' => 0]);
            
        }
        
      

        $this->Flash->set('Record deleted successfully..!', ['element' => 'success']);
    }

    else {
        $this->Flash->set('Error while deleting the record', ['element' => 'error']);
    }
    $this->redirect(array("controller" => "Report", "action" => "someIssued"));
 

            
     }         }                                  
    }
```

Comment: CakePHP version? have you tried placing the logic in afterDelete() or behavior?

Comment: cake php 3.9 and i tried the function after delete.